# Sqlite INSERTION optimization

Tags: sqlite

Good day SO,

I'm working on a program in PowerShell to manipulate an SQLite DB I created. I've never written a serious applications to utilize a DB so right now I'm super interested in optimizing my querys, so I'm really interested in feed back. My primary issue is I have a lot of data that I want to include in a separate table that may or not exist already. All my research really seemed to lead to perform an INSERT and let the UNIQUE constraints sort it out, than do a select on the new record which seemed like two table scans and inefficient. So my solution was Create a temp table, insert into the temp table FROM the table with data I want  and perform an INSERT if the data was not in the temporary table. I'm a few drinks in tonight and haven't tested the code so please don't critique small typos, I just want to know if my methodology is out to lunch, and if so please provide better direction.

My table is as shown:

```
CREATE TABLE Processes (
    pk                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                               UNIQUE,
    hostname           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    artifacttype       INTEGER REFERENCES ArtifactType (pk),
    processname        INTEGER REFERENCES ProcessesName (pk),
    filelocation       INTEGER NOT NULL
                               REFERENCES files (pk),
    pid                INTEGER,
    ppid               INTEGER,
    starttime          INTEGER,
    stoptime           INTEGER,
    token              STRING,
    logonid            INTEGER,
    exitstatus         INTEGER,
    threadcount        INTEGER,
    commandline        INTEGER REFERENCES ProcessesCommandline (pk),
    user               INTEGER REFERENCES users (pk),
    PeakVirtualSize    INTEGER,
    VirtualSize        INTEGER,
    PeakWorkingSetSize INTEGER,
    suspicious         BOOLEAN,
    malicious          BOOLEAN
);
```

Transaction:

```
@"
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Results(pk INTEGER, data TEXT);
INSERT INTO Results(pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT pk, name FROM ProcessesName WHERE name = @processname));
INSERT INTO ProcessesName(name) VALUES (SELECT @processname WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @processname));
INSERT INTO Results (pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT last_insert_row_id, @processname WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data =@processname)));

INSERT INTO Results(pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT pk, file FROM Files WHERE file = @filelocation));
INSERT INTO Files(file) VALUES (SELECT @filelocation WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @filelocation));
INSERT INTO Results (pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT last_insert_row_id, @filelocation WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data =@filelocation)));

INSERT INTO Results(pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT pk, commandline FROM ProcessesCommandline WHERE commandline = @commandline));
INSERT INTO ProcesseCommandline(commandline) VALUES (SELECT @commandline WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @commandline));
INSERT INTO Results (pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT last_insert_row_id, @filelocation WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data =@commandline)));

INSERT INTO Results(pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT pk, SID FROM Users WHERE SID = @SID));
INSERT INTO Users(SID) VALUES (SELECT @SID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @filelocation));
INSERT INTO Results (pk, data) VALUES ((SELECT last_insert_row_id, @SID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data =@SID)));



INSERT INTO processes(hostname, artifacttype, processname, filelocation, pid, ppid, starttime, threadcount, commandline, user, PeakVirtualSize, VirtualSize, PeakWorkingSetSize) 
VALUES (@hostname, @artifacttype, (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @processname), (SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data @filelocation), @pid, @ppid, @starttime, @threadcount, (SELECT pk FROM Results where data = @commandline), SELECT pk FROM Results WHERE data = @SID, @PeakVirtualSize, @VirtualSize, @PeakWorkingSetSize);
DROP TABLE Results;
"@
```

*there are a few foreign keys where the data is being tracked application side so no complex queries are required.

So my core question is, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there a question here?  What are you asking?

Comment: Is this an optimal method of data insertion? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30562.powershell-accessing-sqlite-databases.aspx

Comment: Do you really need `AUTOINCREMENT` (probably not)? That has overheads (see the first sentence of the linked documentation). You only need `AUTOINCREMENT` if you MUST only ever have an id (pk in your case) that always increases. Just having `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will still give you an id (an alias of the **rowid** column) that is unique but should make the inserts more efficient. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)